# Are questions about getting involved on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was just wondering if questions on how to get involved with Ubuntu and Ubuntu-related development were on-topic here?

Comment: "here" being AU meta? I'd say "no".

Comment: @guntbert: No, I meant on the main site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are on-topic here.

Note that this does not exclude them from any of the other close reasons.

Comment: Which of course does not mean they should not be closed for another reason, e.g. for being too broad or opinion-based if needed.

Comment: @ByteCommander Yep. Now that I'm not on my phone anymore I'll edit that in.